# Laravel Link ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**Pessoal poderia me ajudar? fiz um CRUD, mas não estou conseguindo fazer essa etapa!**

tenho uma pagina que busca todos usuários da minha tabela! criei um botão queria que abrisse outra pagina com detalhes do usuário clicado!

**exemplo :** [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**tenho essas rotas**:

Route::get('/register', [AdminController::class, 'register']);

Route::post('/register', [AdminController::class, 'registerAction']);

Route::get('/sigilo', [AdminController::class, 'sigilo']);

**meu controle:**

que busca usuarios

`public function sigilo(Request $request){

```
$dados = User::get();

return view('admin/page',[
    'dados' => $dados
]);
```

}`

**o link do botão**

`<td><a href="{}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">feito</button></a></td>`

já tentei criar rotas com {id}
mas não conseguir

**acredito que cheguei perto mas não conseguir**

**exemplo como eu fiz**
botão

```
<td><a href="/sigilo/{{sigilo->id}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">feito</button></a></td>
```

**rota**

> Route::get('/sigilo/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'sigiloId']);

public function sigiloId($id){

```
$dados = User::findOrFaill();

return view('sigilo/id',[
    'dados' => $dados
]);
```

}

tentei assim mas não deu certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa de uma rota para levar para os dados do usuário:

```
Route::get('/sigilo/{id}', [SeuController::class, 'show']);
```

No controller precisa de um método parecido com isso:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return view('sigilo.user', [
        'user' => User::findOrFail($id)
    ]);
}
```

Pode encontrar mais aqui: [Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#required-parameters)